# What is the best antonym for "friendship"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

> I looked at my co-worker, on the opposite side of a half-wall. He looked at me. I said, in jest, "This is not a wall representing our friendship a wall representing our ______."
>
> We laughed, knowing that the wall was used to describe or relationship in the same way a half-cup of water in a 1-cup glass is used to describe someone's outlook on life.

What would I use to fill in that blank, which best works as an antonym to `friendship`?

Comment: What do you mean by "antonym" here? So the relationship *is not* a friendship; but can you describe in other words what it *is*?

Comment: @sumelic by "antonym", I mean something that I can use to contrast the word "friendship", where if friendship were x units from a central, neutral line, the other word will be x units on the other side.

Comment: @Supuhstar: Does such a line exist? Not all words for relationships have a single polar opposite. For example, I don't know what the opposite to *marriage* is. I'm worried that different people will have different opinions about what the opposite to "friendship" is; these opinions are probably more based in philosophy than in linguistic knowledge. That's why it would be good if you described the state in more detail, the way you imagine it, so we know what specific type of relationship you'd like to describe.

Comment: "*Best antonym*" is undefined.

Comment: @AndrewLeach  I believe this is a lot more clear to what is being asked. I believe that it should be taken off hold

Comment: I'm asking this because I would like to answer and I do believe my edit made it clear. The User is directly asking for an antonym that is "best" or more preferred when using it.

Comment: So... I did my best to improve the example. Hope that helps?

Comment: *enmity* also was the word I thought apropos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*This is not a friendship; this is an **enmity***.

> : a feeling or condition of hostility; hatred; ill will; animosity;
>   antagonism [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enmity)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on severity/context you could use the word:

#### [Rivalry](https://www.google.com/search?q=rivalry&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> : competition for the same objective or for superiority

Typically you cooperate with your friends and compete against your rivals. It also works well with your given statement:

*This is not a friendship; this is a rivalry.*

I also think this term fits your updated phrase and situation quite well considering coworkers can be *in competition* for a promotion.

*This is not a wall representing our friendship [it is] a wall representing our rivalry.*

Answer (score 2):

[Enmity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enmity):

> - a feeling of hostility or ill will, as between enemies; antagonism
> - a feeling or state of hatred or animosity:

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

***false friendship***

"This is not a friendship; this is a false friendship."  False friends are  friends when things are going well for you.  They are friends when they want something from you -- time, energy, an ear to listen to their problems, help with homework, money.   But when you need a friend, the false friend is not there, and always has an excuse as to why it's a bad time, or what you want can't be done, or why he doesn't want to get in the middle of whatever problem you are having.

There isn't necessarily malice in a false friend, like there is in an enemy, but the false friend just can't be bothered.  It is not clear from the context whether the OP means enmity or false friendship.

With an enemy, you know what you are to him.  It can take quite a while before you understand what you are to a false friend.

I found only low-grade references for this term.  But see *Fake Friend/Real Friend Psychology* Today https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-pragmatic-aspie/201109/fake-friend-real-friend

Comment: You could also replace *"false"* with other negative adjectives if you want to describe the reason why this isn't a good friendship. For example you could say *"parasitic friendship/relationship"*